# Finding overlapping polygons within the same layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, geometry, overlapping-features

I have a polygon layer and want to check if there are some polygons overlapping within the same layer. How can I do this?

In ArcGIS, I could run the Intersect tool only by adding the layer I want to check. This doesn't work in QGIS because it requires an overlaying layer.

I tried to add the Topology check *"overlap"*, but this only finds overlapping errors of newly drawn polygons, not existing ones.

I also tried the "Select by Attribute" with `overlay_within(@layer)` but:

- It only finds completely overlapping (identical) polygons (I also need to find the polygons that overlap only slightly)
- It does not create a layer (which would be handy)

Comment: "Check" as in "automatically scan and return the overlapping polygons, or their overlapping parts" or as in "scan visually/manually for overlaps"?

Comment: Where can I "check" this?

Comment: What is your definition of "check"?

Comment: you told me to "check" as in "automatically scan and return the overlapping polygons, or their overlapping parts" or as in "scan visually/manually for overlaps". is this a google research or something I can check in a checkbox in a tool?

Comment: "Check" as in "how do you want to do this".

Comment: Ah, I want something automatically checking my layer for overlaps (within the layer) ideally resulting in a new layer of the overlapping parts or at least in a selection of the polygons overlapping eachother (and then manually search where they overlap).

Comment: Run the SAGA polygon self intersection tool which will create new polys for the overlaps which you can then use to identfy overlaps,  or use in the Eliminate tool to automatically get rid of them.  The Overlap Analysis tool will also show you where there are overlaps.  The topology checker should check all polygons, not just new ones.  You may need to save first.  Note in the layer properties -digitizing you can set it so no overlapping is allowed in creating new polygons.  You also have settings on the snapping toolbar to prevent overlap.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a Virtual Layer with DB Manager which joins the table to itself on intersecting polygons, where the id isnt the same.

You need a unique identifier field, mine is named `id`. My layer is named qwerty. Modify layer name (row 3 and 4) and the id column name (row 6) in the query below and execute:

```sql
select  row_number() over() as newid, 
        st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry
from "qwerty" as a
join "qwerty" as b
on st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
and a.id<>b.id
where st_area(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry))>0
```

[image]

The same logic using QGIS processing tools:

1. Field calculate the integer field `tempid` as `@row_number`
2. Intersection (multiple) with Field calculator output as input and overlay layer
3. Extract by expression `"tempid"<"tempid_2"`

[image]

Comment: I have a lot of touching parcels, which share the same border, but don't overlap. This code finds those and creates a line feature. even tough I have created a overlapping polygon. this overlapping section is not found. I don't have any experience with this type of query. is there a way to modify it the way it only finds polygon-results?

Comment: I've added the last line which only select intersections with an area. This should get rid of the lines and any points.

Comment: In my case after executing, in the geometry table there is not only "Polygon" but also "GeometryCollection (Line String ...)". After loading the layer, nothing is showed. I can't even change the symbology or zoom to the selected row. but the result in your screenshot is EXACTLY what I'm looking for :-)

Comment: You probably need to use [CollectionExtract](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.1.html#p10) to extract only the polygons. Can you share your data?

Comment: I love how everyone knows a different way to solve this issue, each one as viable as the next.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you run `join attributes by location`, with both inputs being your polygon layer, using "overlap" as condition and discard all features which haven't been joined to something. Now you're left with all the overlapping features.

If you really need only the overlapping parts, we need to go down the rabbit hole (at least a bit).

1. Add the `$area` to your polygons.
2. Then run `union` with your overlapping polygons as both inputs.
3. `Select by expression` all polygons in your "unionized" layer with an area = 0 or an area equal to the area added in step 1.
4. Delete the selected polygons.
5. Run `delete duplicate geometries` on the overlaps you got.

This probably is also possible using expressions, overlay_intersects or aggregate and whatsoever, but I prefer a working solution over something I need to fiddle around with two hours.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the expression

```
array_length(overlay_intersects(@layer,$id))>0
```

Either use it via **Select by Expression** or run it in **Extract by Expression** to create a new layer containing the overlapping polygons.

Depending on your exact usecase, you may also want to try one of the other overlay expressions.

Comment: I love how everyone knows a different way to solve this issue, each one as viable as the next.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Polygon Self-Intersection` tool if you have SAGA installed.

[image]

- Polygons: the input polygon layer
- Identifier: the field name that you want to use to identify the intersected polygons.
- Intersection: The output intersected polygons.

Then open the attribute table and in the newly added field, look at the attribute values where the pipe character exists <kbd>|</kbd>. These are the polygons that have self-intersections.

Example:

Original polygons:

[image]

After running the tool:

[image]

Comment: I love how everyone knows a different way to solve this issue, each one as viable as the next.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the [LF Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/lftools/) plugin and run the Overlapping polygons tool.

I made a scratch layer with overlapping polygons (brown polygons) then ran the tool and it made a new layer of the parts that overlapped (maroon polygons)
[image]

[image]

Comment: I love how everyone knows a different way to solve this issue, each one as viable as the next.